# National Instruments relay module does not specify minimum switching current

Tags: switches

I was looking at switches from national instruments.
And I have a few questions regarding the datasheets, I hope someone can help.

1. The PXIe 2738's topology is 2-wire 8x32 matrix.
   I do not understand the meaning of 2-wire what is the difference between a **2-wire 8x32** matrix, a **1-wire dual 8x32** matrix and a **1-wire 8x32** matrix?
2. Also the [datasheet of the PXIe2738](https://www.ni.com/docs/de-DE/bundle/pxie-2738-specs/page/specs.html) specifies a minimum switching load of 20mV/1mA.
   But the datasheet of the [PXIe-2532B](https://www.ni.com/docs/de-DE/bundle/pxie-2532b-specs/page/specs.html) does not specify a minimum switching load. Why and what would be the minimum switching load?

Comment: Because: bad datasheet? I'd ask the manufacturer. And if they can't even give you a proper pdf, then I wouldn't even bother with looking at their products.

Comment: It's vital for any serious design to get hold of pdf data sheets because you save them with your project and they form a quality record of what you have designed. If a supplier doesn't produce pdf data sheets (or equivalent) then, when you have an issue with your design, how can you prove what data you based your design on especially if the website has now got modified data. In other words, you cannot control what a website says and, you can't rely on it for device performance.